# ERROR 1200: could not instantiate 'PigStorage' with arguments '[:::]'

Tags: file, delimiter, apache-pig

I have file in my local HDFS and it it is delimited by ':::'.

However when i am using the following command

> A = load '/user/vishal/WordCount/hw3data/c0001' using
>   PigStorage(':::') as (a, b, c);

it gives me the following error----

> ERROR 1200: could not instantiate 'PigStorage' with arguments '[:::]'

What exactly could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: I think Pig will not allow multiple characters as delimiter,you have to change the delimiter of the file manually to single character with unix tr command,later try to load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PigStorage supports *single-character delimiter* only.
A solution would be to either follow Donald's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419865/pig-load-problem-with-multiple-delimiters) or have a look at [MyRegExLoader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MyRegExLoader.html) if you don't want to create a custom loader. In your case it looks something like this:

```
REGISTER '/my_pig_home/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar'
A = LOAD '/user/vishal/WordCount/hw3data/c0001' 
  USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader(
    '([^\\:]+):::([^\\:]+):::([^\\:]+)') 
      as (a:chararray, b:chararray, c:chararray);
```

Comment: Hi Lonard, While trying for the above thing I got the following error                                                           ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Implementing class.What could be the reason

Comment: Which Pig version do you use? Could you provide some more information about the issue (e.g stack trace) ?

Comment: I am using  0.10.1(pig version)
Following is the error---

2013-03-07 14:35:58,235 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Implementing class
Details at logfile: /home/vishal/pig_1362638150546.log

ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Implementing class

Comment: following is stack trace                                                                                                       java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 at j

Comment: at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)

Comment: at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)

Comment: Isn't the end of the first part of the stack trace is missing? I don't see the failing class. Not quite sure, but I'd rebuild piggybank and would also check the classpath if it contains the right Pig version. Some explanation about the IncompatibleClassChangeError: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1980474/1050422

Comment: I had this class compatibility issue. In my case, it is an issue of using different pig version than the piggybank came with. If we use pig that comes out of the trunk, it works